# Java JFileChooser filter files for "File.txt"

Tags: java, jfilechooser, filefilter

How can I make a JFileChooser Filter to filter for "File.txt", I can make it filter for just ".txt" but thats not what I want.

I'm going to have a String[] of files to filter for such as

```
String[] filters = new String[filtersCount];
String[0] = "File.txt";
String[1] = "Text.txt";
String[2] = "uncapText.txt";
```

I want to be able to browse for only files with those exact names, capitalization does also count so `"uncapText.txt"` will be accepted but `"UncapText.txt"` or `"unCapText.txt"` won't.

This seems like an easy question but I couldn't find any topic on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing a filter that checks for...

```
return Arrays.asList(filters).contains(file.getName());
```

In other words, make a List out of your array (to have a nice "contains" method) and then ask that list if the name of the file is contained in it.

Comment: How do I go about making a List out of my Array? (I don't normally use Lists)

Comment: That's what Arrays.asList(...) is for... It creates a list around your array.